# How to run variable of one function to another in python?

Tags: python, function, oop, google-colaboratory, user-defined-functions

I am a beginner. I have two function:
1st creating dataframes and some print statement
2nd is downloading the dataframes to csv in colab.

I want to download all dataframes by the df_name.
code:

```
def fun1():
  import pandas as pd
  d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
  d2 = {'col1': [-5, -6], 'col2': [-7, -8]}
  df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
  df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
  print('info', df.info())
  print('info', df2.info())
  return df, df2
def fun2(df):
  from google.colab import files
  name1 = 'positive.csv'
  name2 = 'negative.csv'
  df.to_csv(name1)
  df2.to_csv(name2)
  files.download(name1)
  files.download(name2)
```

```
fun2(df) #looking something like this that download my df, func2 should read my df and df2 from fun1()
```

I tried:

```
class tom:
  def fun1(self):
    import pandas as pd
    d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
    d2 = {'col1': [-5, -6], 'col2': [-7, -8]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
    print('info', df.info())
    print('info', df2.info())
    self.df= df
    self.df2 = df2
    
    return df, df2
 
  def fun2(self):
    df,df2 = fun1()
    from google.colab import files
    name1 = 'positive.csv'
    name2 = 'negative.csv'
    df.to_csv(name1)
    df2.to_csv(name2)
    return files.download(name1) ,files.download(name2)
```

```
tom().fun2() #it download files but shows print of fun1 as well which I don't want.
```

looking for something like

```
tom().fun2(dataframe_name) #it just download the files nothing else
```

Comment: "shows print of fun1 as well which I don't want" - you should write extra code in `fun1` that'll let the caller decide whether to print anything or not. Right now the function will always print stuff, and the caller basically has no control over this (you could redirect `stdout` somewhere, but it's not worth the trouble)

Comment: Add a parameter to `fun1` like `print_info=True` And then in `fun2` when you call `fun1` include parameter value like `print_info=False`? Or lots of other ways of solving the problem of only printing info in some cases

Comment: is there any other way in fun2() so it reads df1 and df2 from fun1() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set permanent variables directly in the class if its not gonna change and

define fun just for actions.

```
class s:
  import pandas as pd
  
  d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
  d2 = {'col1': [-5, -6], 'col2': [-7, -8]}
  df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
  df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)


  name1 = 'positive.csv'
  name2 = 'negative.csv'
  df.to_csv(name1)
  df2.to_csv(name2)
  def f():
    print('info', df.info())
    print('info', df2.info())
  
  def fun(x):
    from google.colab import files
    return files.download(x)
```

run

```
s.f() --it will print value only
s.fun(s.name1) --it will just download the file
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can save the data you need in a class variable or create another function, that keeps the data from the first function you need the value (lets call it A) and then pass A to the second function as an argument.

Comment: can you write it in a class please